# Directional derivative $f(x,y,z) = \sin(xyz) $

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Using the limit definition, find the direction derivative of $f(x,y,z)=\sin (xyz)$ at the point $P(1,1,0)$ in the direction of $v=⟨2,1,1⟩$.
>
> $D_vf(a) := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+tv) - f(a)}{t}$

Using this definition I get:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f((1+2t,1+t,0+t)) - f(1,1,0)}{t}
=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin{(1+2t)(1+t)(t)} \ -\  \sin (1\cdot1\cdot0)}{t}\\
=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin{2t^3 + 3t^2 +t} \ -\ \sin 0}{t}
\overset{L'Hôp}{=}\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\cos{(2t^3 + 3t^2 + t)}\ \cdot\ (6t^2 + 6t +1)}{1}= 1$$

Is this the correct approach or did I do something wrong?

Comment: How do you get the $6t^2+6t+1$ coefficient?

Comment: @FlorianIngels I think the OP applied L'Hopitals rule.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Is this the answer that you were given to be correct?

Comment: Thanks @Mattos. One should also remark that $2t^3+3t^2+t = t+o(t)$ so that $\sin(t+o(t)) / t = 1+o(1)$. The result is therefore correct, as pointed by Jacob.